# How to use "from ... to ..." in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

In the following sentence I have used **"from ... to ..."** to describe a range of things:

> Plants have contributed to the development of many drugs from common pain relievers like aspirin to medicines for life-threatening illnesses such as cancer.

Is this sentence grammatically correct?  I feel there should be a kind punctuation somewhere in the sentence to help the reader get the point, but I am not sure where it should be! I wanted to mention that some plants have been used to make medicines. Some of them produced drugs that are used to relieve pain, and some others are consumed to treat serious life-threatening illnesses. Is it clear from the sentence?

Comment: The sentence is perfectly clear to me but my grasp of the comma is so shaky that I will leave it to others to give the rule, if one exists.

Comment: Use of commas is more a matter of style than of strict rules, but I think a comma after _drugs_ would make the sentence clearer.